# How to delete a row in MySQL if the condition is met

Tags: mysql, database

I have rows with a column called Flags and I want to delete a certain row when the number of flags reaches 100 in that column.
`SELECT IF(Flags = 100, DELETE, "false") FROM posts WHERE ID = 6;`
This obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE ID = 6 AND Flags >= 100;
```